# How can i get the value from URL search params after %20?

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I have implemented deeplinking functonality in our properly but i have a problem to get the value after %20 in URL My current URL:

https://halarewards.com/geturl.php?URL_SCHEME=HalaRewards://app/alloffers&DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https&DEEPLINK_HOST=halarewards.com&pagename=alloffers&categoryname=Beauty%20&%20Wellness"

In above URL we have get the value of categoryname via searchparams:

//get key value from URL
var name = currentURL.searchParams.get('categoryname');

it will be return Only 'Beauty' instead of a 'Beauty & Wellness'.i will get whole categoryname value from above URL but in my current scenario it will  be return only Beauty.tell me anyone how to get to get the value after %20 in ionic2 or javscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating the URL you would need to [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the ampersand between "Beauty" and "Wellness". For example Beauty%20%26%20Wellness:

```js
const link = 'https://halarewards.com/geturl.php?URL_SCHEME=HalaRewards://app/alloffers&DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https&DEEPLINK_HOST=halarewards.com&pagename=alloffers&categoryname=Beauty%20%26%20Wellness'
const url = new URL(link);
alert(url.searchParams.get('categoryname')); // "Beauty & Wellness"
```

Comment: Sir it is working but i will be return  this - "Beauty &amp; Wellness" instead of Beauty & Wellness ?

Comment: Interesting, which runtime are you using? I've updated the answer to include a code snippet you can run to see the output of "Beauty & Wellness" in Chrome 70.  You could also replace the &amp; with & like so: 'Beauty &amp; Wellness'.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');

Comment: sir i am also using chrome 70 for runtime..replace(/&amp;/g, '&'); its working for me sir and thank you for depth information regarding URL(ampersand) thanks a lot sir.

Comment: Glad to to hear it’s working for you. Please accept the answer to help others :)